# Jquery div expands all divs on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".content").hide();
        jQuery(".link").click(function()
        {
          jQuery("div.content").slideToggle(500);
        });;
    });
</script>
```

How to expand only the div which is linked to the specific link?

Edit:
Its done like this

```
<div class="comment">
   <div class="bar">
      <a class="link">#</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="comment">
   <div class="bar">
      <a class="link">#</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user... Please MARK AS 'GOOD ANSWER' your accepted answer! Stack Overflow is a community site where pros and non-Pros help you just for a 'RIGHT ANSWER' check! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

You changed your HTML. Now do this:

```
jQuery(this).closest('div.comment').next('div.content').slideToggle(500);
```

But wait! Now you have 2 different `div.link` elements in different relation to `.content` elements. Is this your ***actual*** HTML markup?

You could also do this:

```
jQuery(this).closest('div.content').slideToggle(500);
```

Please provide your actual HTML.

---

<s>**EDIT:**</s>

Based on updated question, do this:

```
jQuery(this).parents('div.blaat1').eq(1).next().slideToggle(500);
```

> *How to expand only the div which is linked to the specific link?*

How are they linked?

If the `div` is a descendant, do this:

```
jQuery(this).find('div.content').slideToggle(500);
```

If the `div` is a an ancestor, do this:

```
jQuery(this).closest('div.content').slideToggle(500);
```

If the `div` is the next sibling, do this:

```
jQuery(this).next().slideToggle(500);
```

If the `div` is the previous sibling, do this:

```
jQuery(this).prev().slideToggle(500);
```

Without seeing your HTML structure, we can only guess at the solution.

Comment: @user: I see you changed your HTML. Of course it doesn't work. I'll update.

Comment: This question started out so promising didn't it!

Comment: jQuery(this).closest('div.comment').next('div.content').slideToggle(500);

Did the job wonderfully, thank you very much!
Im sorry i couldn't provide the actual html, it would be over 200 lines.

Comment: @user: That's alright. Just try to make the code in the question as close of an actual reproduction of the issue as possible. :)

Answer (score 1):

For this HTML:

```
<div class="blaat1">
   <div class="blaat1">
      <a class="link">#</a>
    </div>
   <div class="blaat2">
      <a class="link">#</a>
    </div
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="otherdivs">
      <div class="blaat1_div"><p>Hi – I'm blaat 1</p></div>
      <div class="blaat2_div"><p>Hi – I'm blaat 2</p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Use this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".content").hide();
        $(".link").click(function() {
          var blaat = $(this).parent().attr("class");

          $(blaat+"_div").slideToggle(500);
        });;
    });
</script>
```

I haven't tested that, but it should work.

Comment: Hmm now it isn't working anymore.
The link is in a diffrent div then the content,  can that cause a problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread it, I thought you wanted .link to slide. Can you post your HTML?

Comment: What does otherdivs look like? I'll suggest a better way!

Comment: You can basically see it as another comment, i will explain it a little more in first post, thanks for all the fast help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".link").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('div.content').slideToggle(500);
});;
```

Comment: @user711096 it may work. please test this. if not please comment me.